# difference between present simple and future simple

Tags: grammar, present-tense, future-tense

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

The first one is in present simple tense and
second one is in future simple tense but the difference in the meaning is not clear.

> We fly to Paris next week.

> We will fly to Paris next week.

Comment: [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226650/is-it-correct-to-say-we-start-tomorrow-shouldnt-it-be-we-are-starting-tomor) answers your question much better...